# Backticks entered on iPad not recognized by StackExchange as 'code' markdown

Tags: ios, ipad

I mostly work with StackExchange systems from my PC, but sometimes, I respond using my iPad (iPad Air with iOS 12.5.5).

The StackExchange does not recognize backticks when entered from the iPad. They look to me as backticks, but when sent, they are not recognized as code markdown, but are shown a backticks after hitting "send".

Is there something I can do about this?

(iOS 12.x is the latest available for my iPad)

Comment: Testing `backtick` from iPhone. Can't repro, though I'm on iOS 15. Just checking this is the one you're sending… https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ghu.jpg

Comment: It looks like this on my iPad keyboard: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw8CQ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw8CQ.jpg)

Comment: Hmm… I checked on an iOS 12 iPad & not only is that layout different to mine, but I can't even *find* a backtick on it anywhere.

Comment: what keyboard languages support/layout have you active on your iPad?

Comment: Swissgerman and English. Thanks to your keyboard image, I'v now found that qith the English keyboard, the backtick works.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that while the backtick isn't recognized when working with the *Swissgerman* keyboard, it **does** work when using the *English (US)* keyboard. Not nice but at least a work around.

The backtick is here on theEnglish US keyboard:
[image]

Since there seems to be a backtick on the Swiss German keyboard here: [image], I didn't think of long-tapping on this quote:[image]. Looks the same but isn't, obviously. The latter works a well. Not sure what I'd have to call the former character.

Comment: The first one seems to be https://unicode-table.com/en/02CB/

Comment: Thanks. How did you find out? But it doesn't behave like "grave accent", since I cannot combine with letters, such as "a" to produce "a grave".

Comment: I entered it into the search field at the top of the linked page.